# How to turn flex-direction from row to column when device width is shrinkes(HTML)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am searching for ways to convert my three cards that are standing in a row on the laptop screen to turn into a column view on the mobile screen. Unfortunately, I don't quite know how to execute this.

When on the laptop screen three cards look normal
When on the mobile screen the three cards exceed the width of the general website borders.

Comment: Write `media` query according to screen and set `flex-direction:column;`, or you can set `flex-wrap` property.

Comment: try this element in the head tag  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: I think other developers could help you more, if you put the code of your project in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a basic demonstration using `media-queries`. Essentially just choose a specified width on where you want the flex-direction to change, then set it to `flex-direction: column;`.

View the *full page* and resize the snippet to see it work.

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.flex-item {
  font-size: 4em;
}

.flex-parent > .flex-item:nth-child(2) {
  color: hotpink;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .flex-parent {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <p>hello world</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <p>hello world</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

By default the flex-direction is row. All you need to do is make `flex-direction: column` inside the `@media` rule only for mobile devices. Like that.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
   .your-class-name{
      flex-direction: column;
   }
}
```

Comment: Typo in column.

Answer (score 0):

There is a universal solution to solve your problem. It is necessary to determine whether content overflow occurs in the content or not.
To do this, get the width of all content elements, and compare with the size(width main) of the block itself. And if an overflow occurs, you can change the style.

To measure width, first find the element through query

> ```
> const [isOverflowing, setOverflowing] = useState(false);
>
> useEffect(() => {
>   const checkOverfloying = (element_id) => {
>     const element = document.getElementById(element_id);
>     const container = document.getElementById(container_id);
>     if (!element || !container) return undefined;
>
>     const isOverflowingEl = container.clientWidth < element.scrollWidth;
>     return isOverflowingEl;
>   };
>
>   setOverflowing(checkOverfloying(element_id));
> }, [])
> ```

where *element_id, container_id* - id's of your element and container